# Как получить содержимое между тегами jQuery

Tags: jquery

[image: между тегом div]

Получить из одного тега div и записать в другой div.

Comment: свои предложения есть?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Пробовал .show()

Comment: @Igor С добавить в тег с помощью append() нет проблем, каким методом взять из другого div?

Comment: `text()`, `html()` смотрели уже?

Comment: @Oleksandr .html()   помогло, спасибо.  До этого не правильно пробовал его использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
var text = $("#id").text();  // получит текст
var html = $("#id").html();  // получит html-код
```

Подробнее

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
$('button').on('click', function() { // При клике на кнопку
  var text = $('.in').text();        // Получаем текст с нужного блока
  $('.out').text('Новый ' + text);   // Добавляем этот текст в другой
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="in">hello world</div>
<div class="out"></div>

<button>Заменить текст</button>
```